# Julia where statement in function definition

Tags: types, parameters, julia

I have a function with the header

```
integrateL(f, lb::SArray{Tuple{S},Float64,1, S} where S<:Integer, ub::SArray{Tuple{S},Float64,1, S} where S<:Integer, y::Float64)
    return nothing
end
```

I do not share the content for the issue is not inside and it would be confusing. The issue is reproducible as is. This function performs a semi-infinite multi-dimensionnal integration with HCubature.jl package after transforming the variables. In the arguments I use StaticArrays as advised in the package documentation for performances. To reproduce the error do as follows.

```
lb = zeros(SVector{1}) #1-element SArray{Tuple{1},Float64,1,1}
ub = ones(SVector{1})  #1-element SArray{Tuple{1},Float64,1,1}
f(y) = y ^2
IntegrateL(f, lb, ub, 5.0)
```

the error returned is

```
no method matching integrateL(::typeof(f), ::SArray{Tuple{1},Float64,1,1}, ::SArray{Tuple{1},Float64,1,1}, ::Float64)

Closest candidates are:
integrateL(::Any, ::SArray{Tuple{S},Float64,1,S} where S<:Integer, ::SArray{Tuple{S},Float64,1,S} where S<:Integer, ::Float64)
```

So my guess is that it is not accepting ub and lb as SArray{Tuple{S},Float64,1,S} where S<:Integer types eventhough I specified that S should be an Integer parametric value. I am probably missusing 'where' here. Note that I originally wanted to use

```
::SArray{Tuple{Int64},Float64,1,Int64}
```

in my function definition but couldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know the right words to explain this but `where T <: SomeType` is used for types. 1 in `Tuple{1}` is not a type, but rather a *non-type* parameter.

The following example might make things clear.

```
julia> abstract type Pointy{T<:Real} end

julia> Pointy{1.0}
ERROR: TypeError: in Pointy, in T, expected T<:Real, got Float64

julia> Pointy{Float64}
Pointy{Float64}

julia> abstract type Smooth{T} end

julia> Smooth{1.0}
Smooth{1.0}
```

The solution to your question, therefore, is to replace `where S<:Integer` with just `where S`.

In addition, you might want to use `SVector{S, Float64}` alias instead of `SArray{Tuple{S},Float64,1, S}`.

```
julia> SArray{Tuple{2},Float64,1, 2} === SVector{2, Float64}
true
```

As a side note, I haven't used `StaticArrays` much but I think your function is overly-specific for no benefit. Your function, for example, won't work with built-in `Array`s. If you really need `S` in your function definition, you might just use `length` function just as you would with `Array`s. There will be no performance penalty of doing so with `StaticArrays`, since the call to length will actually be replaced by `S` in compilation time and the compiler will specialize your loops etc. just as in your original function definition.